# Swagger: '500 internal server error' No Error Message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, swagger, swagger-ui, .net-6.0

I have created .net 6 Function App project and used the open api. It is not showing any error messages rather than just status code.

[image]

My API attributes are like below,

```
[OpenApiOperation(tags: new[] { "Libraries" })]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(List<Library>), Description = "Returns list of Library")]
[FunctionName("Libraries")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Getlibraries([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Libraries")] HttpRequest req)
{
        try
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(_LibraryService.GetLibraryDetails());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

 }
```

What is the solution for this? Should I add an additional OpenApi attribute to get the exception response in the response body?

Comment: could you please provide the complete code and what the GetLibraryDetails() method contains so that we can do repro/check from our end!

Comment: Sorry I can not share my office code, please let me know if any additional information reuired

Comment: If it is the default code provided by Microsoft, it's working for us. https://i.imgur.com/ZFfumwt.png. The change I observed from your code is `Libraries` in your OpenApiOperation and some collection List<Library> so tell us briefly what Libraries contains?